# Erro em instalação de pacote

Tags: r, instalador, packages

Iniciei trabalhos utilizando o *R*, e durante a instalação de alguns pacotes como por exemplo o *Devtools*, aparece a seguinte mensagem discriminando o erro:

```
* installing *source* package 'devtools' ...
** package 'devtools' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Simico/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/devtools/DESCRIPTION': No such file or directory
Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") : 
  nÃ£o Ã© possÃ­vel abrir a conexÃ£o
ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'devtools'
* removing 'C:/Users/Simião/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/devtools'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Simião\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\RtmpqyR84v/downloaded_packages/devtools_1.13.4.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status
```

Não sei o que devo fazer, já procurei várias coisas pra concertar o erro, mas não deu certo, meu *OS* é *Windows 7* e a versão do *R 3.4.0*

Comment: Simião, parece que você está tendo problemas de _encoding_. Veja que o erro indica tentativa de carregar de uma pasta "Simico" em vez de "Simião". Eu tentaria mudar o encoding de sua sessão de UTF-8 para latin1.

Comment: Tente instalar como administrador, me parece um problema de permissão

Comment: Como forma de evitar os erros de acentuação, e fazer com o que o código tenha maior fluidez não coloque acentos nos arquivos/pastas/caminhos no R. Caso contrário, você precisará sempre contornar isso, como o @AiltonAndradedeOliveira disse

Answer (score 2):

Olá,

eu também tive um erro similar ao tentar baixar qualquer pacote via devtools::install_github.

Depois de procurar em 'issues' do pacote devtools eu descobri que o problema era o fato do meu diretório do R em C:/Users/'nome do usuário' conter caracteres ASCII. Recomendo fortemente olhar: https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1787

Eu reparei que seu nome de usuário tem um ~ em 'simião'. Acredito que seu problema seja esse. Eu resolvi minha questão retirando o acento do nome da usuário da pasta.

Espero ter ajudado.